# Hii, How do I run a command everytime I get an: "The process "XXX.exe" not found" error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

Basically this is my code, which is supposed to block a software of choice.

```
: import os
import time
import easygui
import subprocess


def main():
    seconds = int(easygui.integerbox())
    file = get_file()
    close_file(file, seconds)


def get_file():
    file_name = easygui.filesavebox()
    return file_name


def close_file(file, seconds):
    if os.path.exists(file):
        while (seconds != 0):
            exe_name = file.split("\\")

            try:
                subprocess.Popen('taskkill /f /im {}'.format(exe_name[-1]))
            except:
                print('Program not open')



            time.sleep(1)
            print(seconds)
            seconds = seconds - 1

        print('You can now use the program.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Every time I run it and not the software is not open I get this repeatedly "Error: The process "blablabla.exe" not found. So basically how can I run a command in case I get such an error?